# Chrome on android - not loading local website javascript and css

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, local

I have strange problem on Chrome for Android with local website.

It works perfect on Firefox for Andorid, but not for Chrome.

On my site here: https://passcombo.com there is download link with a zip file.

What I do is:

1. download file to local file system (not SSD! - external storage makes
   another problem!)
2. I unzip the package and go to the site in local storage using File Commander
3. I open the html file with Chrome - only HTML loads, no CSS, no JS, no images, no fonts.

Looks like there is path problem with relative paths?

But firefox works!

**Working alternative is Firefox, but there you need to write correct strange path: "file:///storage/emulated/0/..../...html"
But...
Currently Chrome is mostly used on Andorid so it's bad local sites not working :/**

Comment: You certainly mean "download file to local file system". Localstorage is a HTML5 feature and is something completely different.

Comment: Download a website in a zip file, unzip it and open the HTML file does not make much sense. The local file system does not behave like a webserver. This is why your linked files do not load. Chrome blocks all links to the file system for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, corrected to local file system. It works for Firefox, so it's not a matter of file system, more Chrome itself. This is normal functionality on regular PC or notebook, not need a server fo that - download page as complete html or download the zip package and it works perfectly... Only Chrome does not on Android, which is a shame... At least there could be and option to unlock it...

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't work opening with file explorer, you have to write the path in the address bar `file:///sdcard/Download...` or wherever. 
`JS` works with `Chrome` on local `html` file in my `Galaxy S6`.

Comment: Doesn't work now in year 2021.  file:///sdcard/ does not show .html files (it shows local folders but not HTML/JS files.)

Comment: @eddie.... It shows all files.. just click on HTML file and you are good'

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I found is to:

1. [update 2021] use Opera (Firefox did work before recent update!)
2. copy folder with my html/css/js to local storage
   (somewhere)
3. open the sitewith path like:
   [current Opera] file:///storage/0000-0000/MyFolder/index.html
   [old  in firefox ] file:///storage/emulated/0/myfolder/index.html

where 'file:///storage/0000-0000/' OR 'file:///storage/emulated/0/' is the main path to local storage, and if you copied your folder somehwre deeper then you need to change the 'myfolder' to /somefolder1/somesubfolder/.../ sth

Shame it's the only way to create a web browser app for adroid.

Comment: I was getting access denied in Firefox, but it was because Storage permission was not granted. Then it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Opera in Android is not showing/opening the .html files, the 'file:///sdcard/' or  'file:///storage/emulated/0/'  does show the folders but no files. Any other ideas/workarounds?  TIA.

Comment: For me current version of Opera 62.3 opens index.html - just need to type correct path file:///storage/0000-0000/MyFolder/index.html   ,  an be sure to grand access .

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using a HTTP server app on your phone.

For example the [SimpleHttpServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server).

Set the "Document Root" in the settings of that app to the folder in which your html files reside. Start the server and you will see a local link.
Click on that link and choose the html file you want to show.

If you declared your assets relatively those assets will loaded, too.

Comment: yes, but this workaround and a bit shame you need to use it; shuold work directly in the browser, like on a desktopn computer :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the only directory Chrome reads local files from is `file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download/`

Answer (score 2):

The only solution worked for me in Android is the HTTP Web Server (I used   [Simple HTTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server)).

**Installing different browsers didn't help:**
(Apr-2021) I tried installing various Browsers (Chrome, FireFox, even ***Opera*** etc.) in Android but none worked. In all cases, when I navigated to the folder containing HTML/JS files using local `file:///` URLs ('`file:///sdcard/`' or '`file:///storage/emulated/0/`') browsers only displayed the folders but no files.
When I used the absolute path to the HTML file the browsers used `content:///` protocol to
render static HTML content, i.e. it did NOT allow execution of JavaScript code.

Comment: Updated the file path - bit different in Opera. Maybe that is the issue? For me it works with Opera 62.3

Answer (score 1):

In my Android OS version 7, to open a local html file with css and javascript in Google Chrome browser (ver. 64.0.3282.123) I have to open it through an address bar typing as  `file://localhost/sdcard/`, then navigating to the file location. In spite of mention `sdcard` in the address, it opens an internal storage (and my device has actual removable sdcard as well).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am also facing this problem. Chrome does not link to other files on the device, but you can use js and CSS by, using  `<script>` and `<style>` tags and these will be included in the web page. But, for other files, like image, audio, videos, etc. it can't be done on Android still without any server established by 3rd party apps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install  a text editor from playstore . Its name Acode
2. Got to your local file storage , then choose your .html file and press long time.
3. After press long time on .html file , you will see more (left side of your phone screen)
4. From more menu, chose open with option
5. Choose Acode text editor
6. When html file open on Acode editor, then preview it from Acode text editor.
   that's all. It will works 100%.. (sorry for my english)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30274457)