# Why is my CSS not loading in my HTML local file saved on android?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to run my index.html file in the chrome browser (I've tried other browsers as well and not loading css code).

Basically, the issue is that I've run my code on my fedora workstation O.S and it has loaded the CSS code properly. I've linked successfully and any change I make in the styles.css file it will automatically change the appearance on my index.html

Howeve, when running the same code on my android chrome browser it just loads the HTML code.

I keep looking for tutorials or how to solve this problem. I'd really appreciate any help or feedback on how to solve this.

I've tried to add internal CSS and it has worked, the issue seems to be with external CSS through the  tag.

Comment: Can you check the browser console to see if the CSS file is linked properly?

Comment: Where is the HTML file stored and where is the CSS file stored on the Android device?

Comment: The HTML fIle is on same directory as well as the CSS file.

Comment: For computer the CSS is linked properly.

Comment: [Chrome on android - not loading local website javascript and css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41430244)

Answer (score 0):

You need a localhost for that. When you try to open an html file using your browser on Android, **THE BROWSER WILL JUST OPEN THAT SINGLE FILE** (I don't know why it just happens on Android) So you need at least a static local server for that. If you are using android, there are multiple options for you.

Most of android code editors like TrebEdit, Acode or Spsk editor have a simple local server(Free download on google play).
You also can use Termux app to use terminal tools and create even a localhost for backend and databases (php, nodejs, etc).

if you just want a simple web server just download one of that apps from google play, but if you are an android user (without access to PC) who wants to learn development (Like me), It is better to learn to use Termux as soon as possible (But you don't have to if you are just starting to learn for now)

If you can use terminal on your android phone, node package `http-server` is one of best options. If you installed nodeJS, just run : `npm i -g http-server` and then anytime use command `http-server` on your project directory.